# comment function with laravel, where is the mistake?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm creating a blog with the laravel framework. I'm doing a commentary function right now and finished the basic structure for that. Well, there is an error of an undifined variable ($comments )in my view, so I think there are some problems in my controller or routes. Maybe someone of you can have a look over it?

my routes for the commentary function:

```
Route::post('/comment', ['as' => 'postComment', 'uses' => 'Test\\TestController@comment']);
Route::get('/comment/{id}', ['as' => 'getComment', 'uses' => 'Test\\TestController@getcomment']);
```

the controller with the commentary functions:

```
     public function comment(CommentRequest $request)
{
    Comment::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->back();
}

public function getcomment($id)
{
    $comments = Comment::where('thread_id', $id);
    return view('test.show', [
        'comments' => $comments
    ]);
}
```

and the view where I'm trying to get the comments:

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
    {{ $comment }}
@endforeach
```

the comment function where I'm saving the comments in the database works defenetly.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I will update my getcomment function, the: $comments = Comment::query()->findOrFail($id); isn't right of course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code only *creates* the query, you're not actually *executing* the query. You should do that with the `get()` method like this:

```
Comment::where('thread_id', $id)->get();
// Result: array of Comment objects.
```

Your code:

```
Comment::where('thread_id', $id);
// Result: Query builder object (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder).
```

To illustrate, you could use the query builder object like this:

```
// Create the query.
$query = Comment::where('thread_id', $id);
$query->where('content', 'LIKE', '%laravel%');

// Execute the query and return the actual comments.
$comments = $query->get();
```

Comment: You need to call `get()`, like I stated in my answer

Comment: oh yes, sorry... well I'm getting the comments of the right thread if I'm returning the variable ( in  controller: return $comments) -- but if I'm sending this variable to my view, I'm still getting the error of this undefined variable

Comment: okay I made it. I haven't changed the code but I put the code in another function cause my view was kind of confused by the different variables it was trying to get from different functions.

Comment: You can always use the function `dd()` and pass to is the `$comments` variable that you are getting from the db, it will dump the contents of your variable to the screen, maybe that will help you further along.